# Kernel Panics and Three Beeps

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, kernel-panic

Here's the log from my problem report. I'd really appreciate if someone could take a look at it. I should also mention that my computer has been freezing and beeping three times. I removed google drive from my computer as I had seen it caused problems with previous versions of OS X, and I reinstalled the OS. Neither has fixed the issue.

I have a 13 inch 2011 Macbook Pro. OS X Mavericks 10.9.5.

---

```
 Anonymous UUID:       92DD52E1-7A31-2D1C-094A-3C09E0C092A4

 Wed Oct  1 11:54:48 2014 panic(cpu 3 caller 0xffffff800f0dc43e):
 Kernel trap at 0xffffff800f1e2e9d, type 14=page fault, registers: CR0:
 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0x00000000000deadf, CR3: 0x000000000870502b,
 CR4: 0x00000000000606e0 RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX:
 0xffffff801c5aea50, RCX: 0x00000000000deadf, RDX: 0x0000000000000000
 RSP: 0xffnfff80a9ea3d70, RBP: 0xffffff80a9ea3d70, RSI:
 0x000000004463b6a5, RDI: 0xffffff801c5aea50 R8:  0x0000000000000001,
 R9:  0x0000000000000000, R10: 0x0000000000000000, R11:
 0x0000000000000246 R12: 0x0000000000000000, R13: 0xffffff801c5aeaa0,
 R14: 0x0000000000000000, R15: 0xffffff801bfc88d0 RFL:
 0x0000000000010246, RIP: 0xffffff800f1e2e9d, CS:  0x0000000000000008,
 SS:  0x0000000000000010 Fault CR2: 0x00000000000deadf, Error code:
 0x0000000000000002, Fault CPU: 0x3

 Backtrace (CPU 3), Frame : Return Address 0xffffff80a9ea3a00 :
 0xffffff800f022f79  0xffffff80a9ea3 Model: MacBookPro8,1, BootROM
 MBP81.0047.B27, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.3 GHz, 4 GB, SMC
 1.68f99 Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In, 384 MB Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz,
 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353737334448302D4348392020 Memory Module: BANK
 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80CE,
 0x4D34373142353737334448302D4348392020 AirPort:
 spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xD6), Broadcom
 BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.22) Bluetooth: Version 4.2.7f3 14616, 3
 services, 15 devices, 1 incoming serial ports Network Service: Wi-Fi,
 AirPort, en1 Serial ATA Device: WDC WD5000BPKT-75PK4T0, 500.11 GB
 Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-898 USB Device: Hub USB Device:
 BRCM2070 Hub USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller USB Device:
 Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera
 (Built-in) USB Device: Hub USB Device: IR Receiver Thunderbolt Bus:
 MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 22.1
```

Comment: 3 beeps indicate the RAM problem. Run the AHT test to verify, run a Apple Hardware Test (if you have one installed) or use this test http://www.memtest86.com/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please use code formatting for log output! Quote formatting doesn't preserve line breaks and is very difficult to read.

Comment: Could you 1- Start in Safe mode to test 2- Provide bit longer Console report with proper formatting so we can actual read it.

Answer (score 1):

Beeping usually indicates a problem with RAM, though I think it can indicate other hardware problems too.   According to [Mac computers: About startup tones](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5860):

"3 successive tones, a 5 second pause (repeating): This indicates RAM does not pass a data integrity check."

Google Drive is probably installing a driver of some sort that is currently incapatible and causing problems.  Confirm that you're running the latest version of Google Drive's software and update your OS if any updates are available.

Google addresses this problem [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/NVy9cxgkL_g%5B1-25-false%5D) with a link to an update which sounds exactly like the problem you're having.